# apply my function if...else statement with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

My input:

```
    frame   user1   user2   sum_result
0   0          0    0        0     
1   1          0    0        0
2   2          0    1        1
3   3          1    1        2
4   4          1    0        1
5   5          0    0        0
```

I want apply `my_func` with condition to `sum_result'.

That my condition: if `sum_result`=2 return `'ICV'`, if `sum_result`=1 and number of `frame` less(<=10) or equal number of `frame` with result 2  than return `'ReviewNG'` (number of `frame` within `sum_result`=2 minus number of `frame` within `sum_result`=1, so result less or equal 10), if `sum_result`=0 return 'Other'.

For example output that I expected:

```
    frame   user1   user2   sum_result Result
0   0          0    0        0          Other
1   1          0    0        0          Other
2   2          0    1        1          ReviewNG
3   3          1    1        2          ICV
4   4          1    0        1          ReviewNG
5   5          0    0        0          Other
```

That my code:

```
def result_func(row):
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if row==2:        
        return('|ICV')
    elif row==1 & (df['frame'][i]-df.loc[df['sum_result']==2,'frame'].iloc[0]<=10 | df['frame'][i]-df.loc[df['sum_result']==2,'frame'].iloc[-1]<=10):
        return('ReviewNG-ICV')
    elif row==0:
        return('Other')
    else:
        return ""
```

and applying on df:

```
df['result']=df['sum_result'].apply(lambda row: result_func(row))
```

But I have Error:

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

I understand if in my df no condition to `sum_result`=2 it make error. How I can fix my function?

Comment: By the way, you're unconditionally returning inside a for-loop. This is the same as not having the for-loop and setting `i = 0` at the top of the function, which is likely not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no row in the dataframe meets the condition `sum_result=2`, then the series `df.loc[df['sum_result']==2,'frame']` is empty. In this case, you cannot acces the first or last element of it with `df.loc[df['sum_result']==2,'frame'].iloc[0]` or `df['frame'][i]-df.loc[df['sum_result']==2,'frame'].iloc[-1]`. This is what triggers your `IndexError`.
So, first of all, you should check if `df.loc[df['sum_result']==2,'frame']` is actually empty with:

```
if df.loc[df['sum_result']==2,'frame'].empty:
    ...
```

an example of your code could be:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

def result_func(row):
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        if row==2:
            return('ICV')
        elif row==1:
            if df.loc[df['sum_result']==2,'frame'].empty:
                return ('No sum_result==2')
            else:
                if (df['frame'][i]-df.loc[df['sum_result']==2,'frame'].iloc[0]<=10 | df['frame'][i]-df.loc[df['sum_result']==2,'frame'].iloc[-1]<=10):
                    return('ReviewNG-ICV')
                else:
                    return('To be defined')
        elif row==0:
            return('Other')
        else:
            return ""

df['result']=df['sum_result'].apply(result_func)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def result_func(row):
    if row['sum_result'] == 2:
        return "ICV"
    elif row['sum_result'] == 1:
        new_frame = df.loc[df['sum_result']==2,'frame']
        if not new_frame.empty and (row['frame']-new_frame.iloc[0] <=10 or row['frame']-new_frame.iloc[-1] <=10):
             return('ReviewNG-ICV')
    elif row['sum_result'] == 0:
        return "Other"
    return "OTHER UNDEFINED VALUES"
df['result']=df[['frame','sum_result']].apply(result_func,axis=1)
```

If you do not wish to access `new_frame` in every loop you can pass arguments to apply funtion

```
def result_func(row,new_frame):
    if row['sum_result'] == 2:
        return "ICV"
    elif row['sum_result'] == 1:
        if not new_frame.empty and (row['frame']-new_frame.iloc[0] <=10 or row['frame']-new_frame.iloc[-1] <=10):
            return('ReviewNG-ICV')
    elif row['sum_result'] == 0:
        return "Other"
    return "OTHER UNDEFINED VALUES"
new_frame = df.loc[df['sum_result']==2,'frame']
df['result']=df[['frame','sum_result']].apply(result_func,args=(new_frame,),axis=1)
```

Output

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))

+----+---------+---------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|    |   frame |   user1 |   user2 |   sum_result | result       |
|----+---------+---------+---------+--------------+--------------|
|  0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |            0 | Other        |
|  1 |       1 |       0 |       0 |            0 | Other        |
|  2 |     100 |       0 |       1 |            1 | test         |
|  3 |      88 |       1 |       1 |            2 | ICV          |
|  4 |       4 |       1 |       0 |            1 | ReviewNG-ICV |
|  5 |       5 |       0 |       0 |            0 | Other        |
|  6 |      18 |       1 |       1 |            2 | ICV          |
+----+---------+---------+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

Hope it helps